# base64 to image, corrupt image

Tags: python, python-2.7, base64

I have this code:

```
with open("bla.png", "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(image.decode('base64'))
```

and this base64: https://pastebin.com/MKjEdmub
The base64 code comes from a canvas from the front-end. I've verified that the string is exactly the same frontend and backend.

If I try to run the code the current base64 code it says: `Error: Incorrect padding`. I did a bit of research and it turns out that it needs a certain amount of bytes to be converted correctly, hence why it needs `=` at the end of the string. In this case it needs `==` at the end of the string. When I do that it converts fine, but the image is corrupt (unreadable).

When I use an online convertor, the current base64 works fine. When I add `==` it doesn't work in those as well.

I also tried with the `decodestring` function from the base64 library, but that gave the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `str.decode('base64')` on your data works fine for me, did you remove the `data:image/png;base64,` header at the beginning? If I don't remove it I also get a padding error. The online tools that you've tried might check for this common syntax and remove it automatically before decoding.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Florian! I never knew that the header should be removed. Working now!